# On AWS, run an AWS CLI command daily

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-emr

I have an AWS CLI invocation (in this case, to launch a configured EMR cluster to do some steps and then shut down) but I'm not sure how to go about running it daily.

I guess one way to do it is an EC2 micro instance running a cron job, or an ECS task in a micro that launches the command, but that all seems like it might be overkill. It looks like there's also a way to do it in Lambda, but rom what I can tell it'd be kludgy.

This doesn't have to be a good long-term solution, something that's suitable until I can do it right (Data Pipelines) would work just fine.

Suggestions?

Comment: Instead of AWS CLI invocations, use the AWS SDK running in a scheduled Lambda function. This way you only pay for the execution time.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the whole task that you are doing, but to avoid doing it:

> 1. Manually
> 2. Avoid another set up for resources in AWS (as you mentioned)

I would create a simple job in a `Continuous Integration (CI)` server like `jenkins,bamboo,circleci .....` (list can go on). I would assume that you might already have a CI server running, why not use it?

Answer (score 1):

If it is not a strict requirement to use the AWS CLI, you can use one of the AWS SDK instead to programmatically invoke Lambda.

- Schedule a CloudWatch Rules using [cron](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html#CronExpressions)
- When configured, the CloudWatch Rules will trigger a Lambda function
- Implement a Lambda function that calls EMR using one of the supported SDKs (e.g. the [EMR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EMR.html) class in the AWS JavaScript SDK)
- Make sure that you have the IAM configuration in place

Full example is available in the [Schedule AWS Lambda Functions Using CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html)

Kludgy? Yes, configuration is needed, however if you take into account the amount of work required to launch EC2 / ECS (and make sure that it re-launches in the event of failure), I'd say it evens out.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I went with (using the Go SDK).