# Move files in S3 bucket to folder based on file name pattern

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have an S3 bucket with a few thousand files where the file names always match the pattern {hostname}.{contenttype}.{yyyyMMddHH}.zip. I want to create a script that will run once a day to move these files into folders based on the year and month in the file name.

If I try the following aws-cli command

```
aws s3 mv s3://mybucket/*.202001* s3://mybucket/202001/
```

I get the following error:

```
fatal error: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Key "*.202001*" does not exist
```

Is there an aws-cli command that I could run on a schedule to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the way forward would be through the [--filter parameter used in S3 CLI commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters).

So, for your case,

```
aws s3 mv s3://mybucket/ s3://mybucket/202001/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.202001*"
```

should probably do the trick.

For scheduling the CLI command to run daily, I think you can refer to [On AWS, run an AWS CLI command daily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53735738/on-aws-run-an-aws-cli-command-daily)

Comment: Thanks, embarrassed I didn't notice the include and exclude params my self.

Comment: Side note, if you run the script more than once with the --recursive option, files in s3://mybucket/202001/ get moved to s3://mybucket/202001/202001/. I removed the recursive option to fit my needs.